# can't set bounty for a question

Tags: support, bounties

I want to set bounty for a question asked by me but I couldn't. I can't understand why. Here is the question: [jQuery code is making conflict with others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156281/jquery-code-is-making-conflict-with-others)

Answer (score 3):

You asked it 7 hours ago.

Bounties can only be posted on questions that are over 2 days old.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.